# Getting PID's with Ruby and FFI

Tags: ruby

I'm currently trying to determine the name of a parent process that launched a Ruby script. I might be very wrong (and don't hesitate in that case to point me to a simpler way of doing things), but I understand that the only way to do that is to rely on the FFI library.

So, I've installed the necessary packages (I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, so I ran `sudo apt-get install libffi-*`, which installs among other things libffi-ruby1.8 and libffi-dev), then I pasted the [example available here](http://blog.headius.com/2008/10/ffi-for-ruby-now-available.html) into irb1.8, which failed as you can see below:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'ffi'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 
irb(main):003:0* module GetPid
irb(main):004:1>   extend FFI::Library
irb(main):005:1> 
irb(main):006:1*   attach_function :getpid, [], :uint
irb(main):007:1> end
LoadError: no library specified
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/ffi/library.rb:79:in `ffi_libraries'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/ffi/library.rb:106:in `attach_function'
        from (irb):6
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/ffi/memorypointer.rb:33
irb(main):008:0>
irb(main):009:0* puts GetPid.getpid
NoMethodError: undefined method `getpid' for GetPid:Module
     from (irb):9
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/ffi/memorypointer.rb:33
irb(main):010:0>
```

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You now need to explicitly specify the library you want to import functions from.

```
e.g. (untested, but should be close)

require 'ffi'
module LibC
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'c'  # ** this line is now needed **

  attach_function :getpid, [], :uint
end
```

There are more basic examples over at https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Basic-Usage

Btw, you can just use Process.pid to get the current process's pid, or Process.ppid to get the pid of its parent - see http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html

Comment: Answering my above comment: under Unix, `File.open("/proc/XXX/cmdline","r").readline()`, where XXX is the PID of the wanted process.